# How to populate JavaFX TreeView using JarEntries (packages - files)

Tags: java, javafx, treeview

Baically, I'm looping through `JarEntry` classes from a `JarFile` and trying to add each package as a node on the `TreeView<String>`.

Annoyingly, the packages are returned being split up by slashes. Meaning: I have to split each package name into an array and then check if each part (package) already exists in the tree.

Here's an example of what I'm working with:

`org/something/commons
org/something/commons/more`

I need to somehow work with each of these strings to create this kind of structure:

- root

  - org

    - something

      - commons
      - more

After that I'll need to add each class file from non directory entries to each pre-existing directory nodes.

This is honestly the more confusing thing I've ever tried to achieve. I just can't think up a good algorithm for doing this except creating some form of extending treeitem class that acts as an entry wrapper or something like that.

Any guidance would be much appreciated. My current code is like:

```
private void populateTree(Enumeration<String> jarEntries) {

    jarFile.stream().forEach(entry -> {
        String entryName = entry.getName();
        if (entry.isDirectory()) {
            String[] packages = entryName.split("/");

            for(String packageName : packages) {
                // check if already exists in root node
                if(root.getChildren().contains(root.getChildren().indexOf(packageName))) {
                    TreeItem<String> packageNode = root.getChildren().get(root.getChildren().indexOf(packageName));
                    packageNode.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(packageName));
                } else {
                    root.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<String>(packageName));
                }
            }

        } else {
            // it's a file
            String fileName = entryName.substring(entryName.lastIndexOf("/"), entryName.length());
            String[] packages = entryName.substring(0, entryName.lastIndexOf("/")).split("/");
            // somehow loop through each child of the root node and eventually, using some form of traversal algo, get to the package node to add new item to
        }
    });

    root.setExpanded(true);

}
```

This produces the incorrect output of:
[image: Incorrect output, it just adds the packages again and again to the root instead of building on top of already added, existing, package nodes.]

Comment: Is there a reason you are using a `TreeView<String>` instead of the more obvious choice of a `TreeView<JarEntry>`?

Comment: @James_D  I'm just trying to wrap my head around a way to get this done. The TreeView is now using JarEntry, I just need to see if I create the loop that adds each entry in a tree structure.

Comment: Yeah, it's actually kind of tricky... apparently you're not guaranteed to get the directory entries present, so you have to deal with the case where they may be missing.

Comment: @James_D The really annoying part is trying to re-create the directory structure with treeitems. So far I've got it working but since the entry (I'm assuming) is using toString() when deciding what to use as text for the item, it shows the whole path anyway:
http://i.imgur.com/vRB5Krf.png

Comment: Yeah, isn't that fun. I suspect there's a cleaner way to populate the tree than the way I did it, but the key idea is to use a cell factory to show only the last path element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a `TreeView<JarEntry>`, so the data wrapped by the `TreeItem`s are the `JarEntry` objects. Then use a `cellFactory` to instruct the cells to display only the last part of the path.

Actually populating the tree is kind of tricky, because a jar file doesn't need to have entries for its directories. So you may end up having to create new entries as you build the structure. I'm not sure I follow the method you posted: aren't you adding all packages and their subpackages directly to the root (instead of subpackages to packages)?

Here's a SSCCE. You might be able to find a cleaner implementation of populating the tree...

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser.ExtensionFilter;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class JarFileTreeView extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeView<JarEntry> tree = new TreeView<>();
        tree.setShowRoot(false);
        TreeItem<JarEntry> root = new TreeItem<>();
        tree.setRoot(root);

        // only display last portion of the path in the cells:
        tree.setCellFactory(tv -> new TreeCell<JarEntry>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(JarEntry item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    String[] pathElements = item.getName().split("/");
                    setText(pathElements[pathElements.length - 1]);
                }
            }
        });

        ObjectProperty<JarFile> jarFile = new SimpleObjectProperty<>();
        jarFile.addListener((obs, oldFile, newFile) -> {
            if (newFile == null) {
                root.getChildren().clear();
            } else {
                populateTree(root, newFile);
            }
        });

        FileChooser chooser = new FileChooser();
        chooser.getExtensionFilters().add(new ExtensionFilter("Jar Files", "*.jar"));
        Button loadButton = new Button("Load...");
        loadButton.setOnAction(e -> {
            File file = chooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);
            if (file != null) {
                try {
                    jarFile.set(new JarFile(file));
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        BorderPane uiRoot = new BorderPane(tree, null, null, loadButton, null);
        BorderPane.setMargin(loadButton, new Insets(10));
        BorderPane.setAlignment(loadButton, Pos.CENTER);
        Scene scene = new Scene(uiRoot, 600, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void populateTree(TreeItem<JarEntry> root, JarFile file) {
        root.getChildren().clear();
        List<JarEntry> entries = file.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());

        // sort by length of path (i.e. number of components separated by "/"), then by name:
        entries.sort(Comparator
            .comparing((JarEntry entry) -> entry.getName().split("/").length)
            .thenComparing(entry -> {
                String[] pathElements = entry.getName().split("/");
                return pathElements[pathElements.length - 1];
            }));

        for (JarEntry entry : entries) {

            // need to find correct parent for entry. That parent (or any of the ancestors)
            // might not exist yet, so we create it if necessary as we search.

            // Split name up into folder, subfolder, etc:
            List<String> pathElements = Arrays.asList(entry.getName().split("/"));

            // Search for parent. Start at root:
            TreeItem<JarEntry> parent = root;

            // Iterate through all elements except the last, traversing tree:
            for (int i = 0; i < pathElements.size() - 1 ; i++) {

                // name of ancestor entry:
                String matchingName = String.join("/", pathElements.subList(0, i+1));

                final TreeItem<JarEntry> current = parent ;

                // update parent with current parent's descendant, matching appropriate name:
                parent = current.getChildren().stream()
                    .filter(child -> child.getValue().getName().equals(matchingName))
                    .findFirst()
                    // it's possible this ancestor didn't yet exist, so we create it, 
                    // and add it to the correct parent:
                    .orElseGet(() -> {
                       JarEntry newEntry = new JarEntry(matchingName);
                       TreeItem<JarEntry> newItem = new TreeItem<>(newEntry);
                       current.getChildren().add(newItem);
                       return newItem ;
                    });
            }
            // after all that, we have a valid parent:
            parent.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<>(entry));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, I'll look and see if I can use your example to create my own, similar, implementation. Thanks.